# Is there a rpm command to check .rpm package installation log

Tags: linux, rpm

Is there a rpm command to check .rpm package installation log when install failed to find out what happened

Answer (score 7):

You can get all the command line help by typing, either

```
 rpm --help
```

or

```
 man rpm
```

You can use the verbosity flag `vv` (two `v` for more) during installation to know more:

```
 rpm -Uvvh foo.rpm --test
```

`--test` does a dry run of the installation, but doesn't write to the disk.. You can remove it to go with a real installation.